# Post text to activeform from separate class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I am trying to post text from a class into an active form and I am having a little trouble figuring out how to do it.  I have seen a bunch about using Invoking to post things across threads/forms but I can't get my class to see any public functions in the activeform.

Example

```
// File: Form1.cs

namespace Form1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public void SetText(string text)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { \\ Always requires invoke
                TextBox1.Text += text + "\n";
        });
    }
}
```

Then my second class that is being run in a second thread (because it is a long process)

```
// File: Class.cs

using Form1;

namespace Form1
{
    public void DoSomething() // Called in Form1
    {
        // Does stuff

        string TextToGoBack; // Has text when DoSomething runs

        // Here is where I get stuck
        Form form = Form1.ActiveForm;

        form.SetText(TextToGoBack); // SetText is not showing up here no matter what I do
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I would not be opposed to using custom events to accomplish the same thing, but I am having a tough time figuring those out as well.

Comment: Where is the class for `DoSomething()`?

Comment: Have you tried `Form1 form = Form1.ActiveForm; `? Basically type of form to be `Form1` not the `Form`

Comment: @sll Wow, that was pretty much the problem haha.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form.ActiveForm` returns a `Form` object, not the instance of your `Form1` class, so does not have a `SetText` method.

You could cast it to a `Form1`, but that would be brittle. I would pass the instance of `Form1` to your `DoSomething` method.